# Selecting a code block from middle of it

Tags: vim

I can select a word when cursor at middle of the word by doing this --> <kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

But can i select a block from middle of it?

For example:

```
def foo(x):
    y = x + 5 --> cursor is in this line 
    return x * y
```

Is there way to select whole block by doing something like <kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>codeblock</kbd> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *paragraph* text object is built-in, so if your block is delimited by empty lines, `vip` (visual mode, select inner paragraph) will select it.

Apart from that, many plugins extend Vim's built-in text objects with custom ones. [vim-dentures](https://github.com/qstrahl/vim-dentures) defines several generally useful ones based on indent. I've once seen one especially for Ruby blocks; you can search [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/) for such.

With my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130), or the [textobj-user plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100), you can even (relatively) easily define your own text objects!

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to consider plugins once you find more elaborate needs. Text objects are very powerful and can be huge time-savers.